# Show division result (in floating point) in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi I'm coding a small program in MIPS that divide 2 between 9 and show the result.This is the code

```
li $v0, 2
div $t0,$t2,$t1
move $a0,$t0
syscall
```

(it's not the full code, just the section handling division)

Where $t1 is 2, $t2 is 9.

So, 2/9 is 0.2222222222222222

But when I run it I only get 0.0

How I show the true result (0.2222222222222222)?

Thanks in advance.